# Iframe sidebar css

Tags: html, css, iframe, alignment, sidebar

I searched a lot but I'm not a developer and what I ended up is a kind of almost working css with (I think) lots of useless code.. sidebar that resizes when the window resizes. Showing the input fields and button not in line. On firefox the difference is not that annoying but in chrome it is a mess..

Index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="29%" style="border:none" align="top" id="iframe_clock" name="iframe_clock" src="http://10.11.12.13:3118/index2.html"></iframe>
<iframe width="24%" height="70%" style="border:none" align="left" id="file2" name="file2" src="file2.php"></iframe>
<iframe width="75%" height="67%" style="border:none" align="right" id="read" name="read" src="read.php"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

file2.php (the sidebar)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pure-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="iframe.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
  $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
});
</script>
</head>

<?php
$conn = pg_pconnect("host=[connection of the server]");
if (!$conn) {
  echo "Can't connect to database.\n";
  exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT name FROM counterparties";
$result1 = pg_query($conn, $sql);
?>

<body>
<div id="sidebar">
     <div id="inputContainer">
<form method="post" action="read.php" class="pure-form">
<fieldset class="pure-group">
<input id="datepicker1" type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="From" name="fdate"><br />
<input id="datepicker2" type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="To" name="tdate"><br />
<input type="text" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Id" name="identification"><br />
<select name="counterparty">
<?php
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result1)) {
echo "<option class=pure-input-1-2 value=$row[0]>$row[0]</option>";
}
?>
<option class="pure-input-1-2" value="%%">ALL</option>
</select>&nbsp;
<select name="direction">
<option class="pure-input-1-2" value="RECEIVED">RECEIVED</option>
<option class="pure-input-1-2" value="SENT">SENT</option>
<option class="pure-input-1-2" value="ALL">ALL</option>
</select><br />
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" onclick="this.form.target='read';return true;">Send</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe.css (the style for the sidebar)

```
body { height: 100% }
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}
#sidebar #inputContainer {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 21px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
}
#inputContainer{
    width: 100%;
}
```

So, the sidebar is inside the iframe on the left, I wish it to begin from the right (close to the right border of its frame) and I wish that when the whole webpage resizes (different monitor resolution) the sidebar would stretch (if not possible to let it stay fixed width) but remaining aligned.. and of course aligned to the right side of its iframe.

I'm sure that lots of the code above is bad so please feel free to modify as you think it would work/look better. Thank you guys!

Comment: Why are you using iframes ?

Comment: Because it is better for what I want to achieve: on the top there is a clock who must never ever be touched, it is a countdown and the sidebar,  read.php must not interfere with it.
The sidebar must show the result somewhere, where the sidebar itself would not disappear.. I thought about an iframe for the sidebar and one for the result.
 ..and then because I suck at developing.. I'm a sysadmin

Comment: The proper way to do this will be PHP with ``include``.

Comment: I know that function, I used in the past. Is it really the best solution..? My main problem is css, never got to learn it.. I would still use tables for everything.
I mean.. any solution is accepted as long as I can give a fixed shape to the pages for every browser and resolution (and keeping the actual behaviour of the clock, sidebar and main content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow did it..

CSS

```
#container
{
    width: 450px;
    max-width: 98%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    left: 20%;
}
#sidebar
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 450px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

And on the html I just changed
`<div id="sidebar"><div id="inputContainer">` TO `<div id="container"><div id="sidebar"> Because this looks cleaner.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I will edit my answer if it's not working.

```
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No I'm sorry but didn't change. you know any site we can share the code and work simultaneously? because probably this would be easier to work on

Comment: Seems a good one! thanks! so this is the original code: https://jsfiddle.net/vqzb4mp1/
if i'm able to add the css-pure style would be great.. I'm editing.. for now the problem I see is that the sidebar takes the whole page going to the right. is it that mess with the final layout?

Comment: @Nihvel What do you want exactly ? You want to align ``#sidebar`` content to right ?

Comment: Yes, to the right. Avoiding that low resolution would mess its content: at the moment when I resize the window the input fields stretch. It is like there is lots of unused space on the right of the sidebar and it easily get stretched. If the final alignment would always correspond to the exact lenght of the 2 dropdown boxes, that would be great